Adding two negative Hex numbers
I am trying to add two hex numbers given in two's compliment: A415 + A555. I'm having a bit of trouble with understanding the two's compliment inversion for adding.
I converted both numbers to binary and converted them to two's compliment since the binary numbers of the above two hex numbers are negative. So I did the following addition with the newly converted numbers:
0101101111101011
+0101101010101011
= 0111011010010110
So for the sum I got, I have to convert it back because its a positive number right now due to the 0 right? And then from there I just have to reconvert that back to hex?

hex A415 is decimal 42005.  hex A555 is decimal 42325.  Why do you say they are negative?

When I converted them to binary they both had 1 as the leftmost bit, maybe I converted wrong

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
